# Iterate through a specific controls property c#

Tags: c#

i need to iterate through a specific controls property and save the that control's property name & value in xml file. i wrote few line but getting error.

```
private void SaveStyle()
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
    settings.Indent = true;
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(Application.ExecutablePath+ @"\Products.xml", settings);

    PropertyInfo[] properties = metroStyleManager1.GetType().GetProperties();
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString(pi.Name,pi.GetValue(((object)metroStyleManager1),null));
    }
}
```

this line is giving error `writer.WriteElementString(pi.Name,pi.GetValue(((object)metroStyleManager1),null));`

next issue which i need to do that i have to read back the controls property data from xml file and set the value as per the controls name. which is not clear to me that how to do it. so please help. thanks

### UPDATE

my full code to save controls property & read back too.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Xml;
using MetroFramework;
namespace CSRAssistant
{
    class Utils
    {
        public static void SaveProperty(System.ComponentModel.Component _Control)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\Products.xml", settings);

            PropertyInfo[] properties = _Control.GetType().GetProperties();
            writer.WriteStartElement("metroStyleManager");
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
            {
                writer.WriteElementString(pi.Name, Convert.ToString(pi.GetValue(_Control, null)));
            }
            writer.WriteEndDocument();

            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }

       public static void ReadProperty(System.ComponentModel.Component _Control)
    {
        string _property = "", _value = "";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\Products.xml"))
        {
            XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\Products.xml");
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                if (rdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (rdr.LocalName.ToUpper() != "METROSTYLEMANAGER")
                    {
                        _property = rdr.LocalName;
                        _value = rdr.ReadInnerXml();
                        if (_property.ToUpper() == "STYLE")
                            ((MetroFramework.Components.MetroStyleManager)_Control).Style = (MetroColorStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(MetroColorStyle), _value);
                        if (_property.ToUpper() == "THEME")
                            ((MetroFramework.Components.MetroStyleManager)_Control).Theme = (MetroThemeStyle)Enum.Parse(typeof(MetroThemeStyle), _value);
                        //else
                        //    _Control.GetType().GetProperty(_property).SetValue(_Control, _value, null);
                    }
                }
            }

            rdr.Close();
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: What error? It matters.

Comment: Which kind of error? GreenBananaException? Please, always provide error details - type, message (even stacktrace can be useful sometimes)

Comment: the error is related to this line pi.GetValue(((object)metroStyleManager1),null) and error message is cannot convert from 'object' to 'string' .

Comment: `GetValue().ToString()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact error would surely help, but I guess your problem is the [WriteElementString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aex0e7zs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which takes two string parameters.

[PropertyInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the other hand returns an object. You have to convert that `object` to a `string`. A possible way would be to call `.ToString()` on it if it's not `null` and use an empty string if it is.

---

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
{
    object obj = pi.GetValue(metroStyleManager1, null);                      
    writer.WriteElementString(pi.Name, obj != null ? obj.ToString() : String.Empty);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i also like to know when i am saving controls property in xml file then how could i read back data from xml and initialize that controls property value from xml file for which i do not have any idea. i search google but found none. so please help me. thanks

Comment: @Thomas you should post a seperate question for that. I'm afraid there is no easy general solution to your second question.

Comment: the things i am looking for that is done and updated here. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
writer.WriteElementString(string localName, string value)
```

expects two string arguments. But `pi.GetValue()` returns value of type `object`. You need to convert second parameter to string:

```
Convert.ToString(pi.GetValue(metroStyleManager1))
```

That will check if value of object is not null, and return empty string if value is null. It also will check if object implements IConvertible or IFormattable interfaces and call appropriate `ToString()` method.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i also like to know when i am saving controls property in xml file then how could i read back data from xml and initialize that controls property value from xml file for which i do not have any idea. i search google but found none. so please help me. thanks